How to deal with such complicated integrals in MATLAB?
I am trying to code the following expression involving four integrals in MATLAB but its not running properly:

This is what I had tried so far:
integrand = @(y, h, z1, z2) (1 / gamma(m_0)) * ...
            gammainc( ((u_1 ./ ...
            (a_1 * zeta_1 * y .* g_1_abs_sq .* h .* P_h1_2 - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * y .*  g_1_abs_sq .* h .*P_h1_2 - ...
            u_1 * a_1 * zeta_1 *  g_1_abs_sq .* h .* z1 - ...
            u_1 * a_1 * zeta_1 *P_h1_2 * z2 .* g_1_abs_sq .* h - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * g_1_abs_sq .* h .* z1 - ...
            u_1 * a_2 * zeta_1 * P_h1_2 * z2 .* g_1_abs_sq .* h)) / ...
            (Omega_0 / m_0)),m_0) .* ...
            (1/gamma(m_0))*((m_0/Omega_0)^m_0)*y^(m_0-1)*exp(-m_0*y/Omega_0).* 1/(2*pi*a_11).*lambda_1*exp(-lambda_1*z1).*lambda_2*exp(-lambda_2*z2);

% Define the outer integral with respect to z2 from 0 to infinity
        outer_integral = @(z2) arrayfun(@(z2_val) integral(@(y,h,z1) integrand(y,h,z1,z2_val ), 0, y_max(z2_val)), 0:1000);
    

    % Perform the integration
   op = integral(outer_integral, 0, 1000);

I am not getting what mistake I am doing. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

As you can tell, Stack Overflow does not do LaTeX. I suggest you [edit] your post and make it readable. Maybe by uploading an image with the rendered equations. Also, please include complete code, there are lots of undefined variables in your code, which means we don't know what it will do.

Thanks for your reply sir. I will change the latex content with an image.  Please assume the value of the constants as 1 and n = 5.

Ok. So if I were to try to run your code, I’d first give n=5, m0=1, g_1_abs_sq=1, and P_h1_2=1. And then for every other undefined variable error I see I assign 1 as well. What would happen then? What error message would I see?

I think MATLAB cant solve such complicated integration ?

Look, nobody is going to run your code just to see what the problem is. Can you describe what you see? "MATLAB can't solve it" doesn't really describe the problem. Does the computation never end? Do you get an error message? Do you get the wrong result?
